# How can I scrape a password-protected website with BeautifulSoup and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, password-protection

I'm trying to get access to an html page that is protected by a password login(username and password). I tried using requests but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
import r
import requests
def Login():

    scrape_url = 'https://www.ecoledirecte.com/Eleves/3668/Notes'

    login_url = 'https://www.ecoledirecte.com/login'

    payload = {
        'username': '***',
        'password': '***'
    }


    with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
        r = session.get(scrape_url)
        print(r.text)
```

I don't get any errors but `print(r.text)` only gives the html code for the login page and not the `scrape_url`.

Comment: Every login page can be different, so no-one can give you an exact answer unless they have done this for the specific page you are accessing.. The non-guesswork way to get requests login to work is to first trace what your browser does to login using a tool like Fiddler (Windows) or mitm (linux), then reproduce the same settings for headers, parameters and data for the requests login. Also in the requests session you should probably GET the login page (as your browser does) to receive cookies before doing the POST to login,

Answer (score 2):

You need to emulate what your browser is doing when you access the website. If you try to login and open up the network monitor in your browser's dev tools ([instructions for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/)), you'll see that the page at https://www.ecoledirecte.com/login simply contains the form, this is not the URL you want to POST to.

Instead when you type in your username, your browser sends a POST request to https://api.ecoledirecte.com/v3/login.awp with a form containing

```
data={
    "identifiant": "username",
    "motdepasse": "pass"
}
```

thus you should change your login code to:

```py
import json
...

    login_url = 'https://api.ecoledirecte.com/v3/login.awp'
    login_data = {
        'identifiant': 'username',
        'motdepasse': 'password'
    }
    payload = {'data': json.dumps(login_data)}
    with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
```